# Error: Can not convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, lambda, overloading

I'm getting the following error:

> Can not convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type

While running this code:

```
namespace solutions  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main()  
        {  
            int i=3, j=4,k,l;  
            k=AddMult(i,j);  
            l=AddMult(i,j);  
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", k,l);  
        }  
        static int AddMult(int ii, int jj)  
        {
            int kk, m;  
            kk= ii+jj;  
            m=ii*jj;  
            return (kk , m);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Check the return type of AddMult

Comment: Also note that declaring/initializing multiple variables on a single line is against Microsoft's C# coding conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx ("Write only one declaration per line.")

Comment: For your future sanity, I suggest you choose more descriptive names for your variables and arguments.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are wanting to return multiple values from the `AddMult` function? It seems that way to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to return more than one value. To do this there are various options but personally I would create a class:

```
public class AddedAndMultiplied
{
    public int Added { get; set; }
    public int Multiplied { get; set; }

}
```

Aand your function becomes:

```
static AddedAndMultiplied AddMult(int ii, int jj)  
{
    int kk, m;  
    kk= ii+jj;  
    m=ii*jj;  
    return new AddedAndMultiplied { Added = kk, Multipled = m };  
}
```

Finally your main function changes to this:

```
var am = AddMult(i,j);  
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", am.Added, am.Multiplied);
```

Comment: looking at the receiving end it doesn't look like that at all!

Comment: Looking at the receiving end is exactly what makes me think he wants both values. He calls the function twice storing result into multiple variables with the assumption that the syntax allows that.

Comment: Yes, but he wants two ints to be returned.

Comment: @DavidG  Can you please let me know , what changes to made at the time of the function calling in the main()

Comment: @DavidG I am sorry, but at that time I didn't realized the error which I am  getting in the main function.. but I found this helpful in returning two values...

Comment: @DavidG now I got that... I was Debugging the program with definition of 'k' and 'l' and now I realize that is no longer necessary.... Thanks again... :)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is with the line

```
return (kk, m);
```

do you maybe want to return just `m`?

Comment: It's interesting, to me anyway, that the compiler considers 'return (kk , m)' to be a lambda expression.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants to return both values, but is not aware of the required syntax.

Comment: @StephenKennedy I don't think there's any other way to parse it than an erroneous start of a `(kk, m) => ...` lambda expression. It may have parsed it as such, detected that a lambda expression is inappropriate, issued an error about that, and not investigated the lambda expression further.

Comment: Yes, you guessed right. Problem was in the same line. I was returning more then a value at a time.... but what to do if I need to return both value??

Answer (score 1):

You specify the return type of the `AddMult` function as `int`, but `(kk , m)` is not an int.

There are multiple options to make this work:

Return an array of integers:

```
static int[] AddMult(int ii, int jj)
{
    int kk, m;
    kk= ii+jj;
    m=ii*jj;
    return new[] { kk, m };
}
```

Define a class that contains two integers and return this class:

```
class Result
{
    public int kk { get; set; }
    public int m { get; set; }
}

static Result AddMult(int ii, int jj)
{
    int kk, m;
    kk= ii+jj;
    m=ii*jj;
    return new Result { kk = kk, m = m };
}
```

Or you can use the generic Tuple class:

```
static Tuple<int, int> AddMult(int ii, int jj)
{
    int kk, m;
    kk= ii+jj;
    m=ii*jj;
    return Tuple.Create(kk, m);
}
```

Edit: You also need to modify your main program accordingly. If you use the integer array:

```
int[] result = AddMult(i,j); 
k = int[0];
m = int[1];
```

Comment: looking at the receiving end it doesn't look like that at all!

Comment: The return (kk , m) and the function name suggest that he's trying to return two values.

Comment: Can not implicitly convert type int[] to 'int' ... getting this error in main function while using first method (at the time of function calling)

Comment: I edited my answer to include the changes to the main program.